# Best way to fit a clothes washer under a counter

Tags: woodworking, tools, appliances

The under the counter space for the washing machine in our laundry room is slightly too low for our washer. I can't push it in any further because the enclosure isn't perfectly square and the washing machine is too high.

[image]

I've already lowered the feet at the bottom to the lowest possible level. To make enough room, I'm thinking of shaving 1/2" or so from the plywood that between the countertop and the machine itself.

The floor is made of tile, and I could also pull out that tile to get the clearance I need, but I prefer to keep it in case of a leak.

Could I remove a layer from the wood under the granite countertop? Since it's already installed, I would have to do it upside down. I have a Dremel tool (with a router bit), a Dewalt Oscillating tool, an orbital sander, and I'm happy to rent something else if I need it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: i think that you meant to say `ever-so-slightly too small`

Comment: Some washing machines are designed so the top casing can be removed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and rather than removing the wood from under the counter, I totally removed the feet from the bottom of the washer and that gave me an extra 5/8". I put some thin furniture felt pads on the corners of the washer and it slid right into the space.

If that doesn't float your boat, the Dremel with a routing bit will be accurate but will take a lot of time whereas a belt sander will knock off the job fast.

Comment: Removig the foot is the easiest.  Ust the hard plastic slide disc on the corners and it will slide right in.

Comment: @Programmer66  Those would work great especially if the felt got wet.

Comment: Thanks @JACK. There's a plastic mounting that's preventing me from lowering the washer any further, do you think I can remove it and attach felt pads on the bottom to get the clearance I need? [Photo](https://photos.app.goo.gl/fKy8wMjGu2NpxLwB9)

Comment: That looks like a shipping bracket of some sort. I'd try to remove it.

Comment: A belt sander will knock off the job fast, so long as you ignore the time you will spend cleaning up the dust that ends up all over the house (not just all over the laundry room!).

Comment: Does the instruction manual state what the purpose of that plastic tab is? My guess is that it is not essential, but you should find out before removing it. Our Samsung washer doesn't have anything like that, at least I don't see one.